# Nginx running without master process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

At the moment I am trying to solve a problem at a server I did not configure, where Puma and Nginx are running. 
Nginx is Listening on Port 80 and the Apps are working but by viewing the processes I see that there are only the worker processes of nginx running.
There is no Nginx Master Process.

Why does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx worker and master process usually run under different users, make sure you list all users processes:

```
# ps axu | grep nginx | grep -v grep
root     11359  0.0  0.0  58412  2624 ?        Ss   Mar10   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data 31785  0.0  0.0  65524 10236 ?        S    Jun14  18:52 nginx: worker process
```

Upon killing master processes it usually kills workers too.
But if for some strange reason it was killed without killing workers - there's no reason for the latter to stop working, they all share the same acceptor socket. Only reload and similar commands will not work